# Check in Trace 32 on which CPU breakpoint stopped

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

Does anyone knows if that is possible to check ID of CPU on which I reached breakpoint?

I want to print it out and resume execution immediately, so likely need a t32 cmd or global variable.

Comment: So you are doing SMP debugging right? (One TRACE32 GUI connected to a chip with several CPU cores?) What kind of ID are you talking about? e.g. JTAG ID, CPU name, Core number, CPU specific core ID, ...

Comment: Sorry, for not being specific here. Ideally, core number. Also, Yes, I am debugging SMP, one GUI connected to SoC with multicore CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the currently active core number with PRACTICE function CORE() e.g. like this

```
PRINT CORE()
```

while you can always execute a command when you hit a breakpoint with the /CMD option of the Break.Set command:

```
Break.Set <addr> /CMD "<TRACE32 command>"
```

Putting both together you get

```
Break.Set 0x10000 /CMD "PRINT ""Core "" CORE() "" stopped at "" PP()"
```

Note: In TRACE32 double-quotes are escaped with double-quotes. Function PP() returns the current program counter. If you want to restart you core immediately add option /RESUME to Break.Set.

Comment: Perfectly explained. Thanks a lot.